# how to apply imgaug augmentation to tf.dataDataset in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I have an application with an input pipeline that uses a `tf.data.Dataset` of images and labels. Now I would like to use augmentations, and I'm trying to use the **imgaug** library for that purpose. However, I do not know how to do that. All the examples I have found use Keras `ImageDataGenerator` or `Sequence`.

In code, given a sequential augmenter like this:

```
  self.augmenter = iaa.Sequential([
        iaa.Fliplr(config.sometimes),
        iaa.Crop(percent=config.crop_percent),
        ...
        ], random_order=config.random_order)
```

I am trying to apply that augmenter to batches of images in my dataset, without success. It seems that I cannot eval tensors since I'm running my augmentations inside a map function.

```
def augment_dataset(self, dataset):
    dataset = dataset.map(self.augment_fn())
    return dataset

def augment_fn(self):
    def augment(images, labels):
        img_array = tf.make_ndarray(images)
        images = self.augmenter.augment_images(img_array) 
        return images, labels
    return augment
```

For example, If I try to use make_ndarray I get an  `AttributeError`: `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'`

Is this due to `Dataset.map` not using eager mode?. Any ideas on how to approach this?

#### Update #1

I tried the suggested `tf.numpy_function`, as follows:

```
def augment_fn(self):
    def augment(images, labels):
        images = tf.numpy_function(self.augmenter.augment_images,
                                   [images],
                                   images.dtype)
        return images, labels
    return augment
```

However, the resulting images have an unknown shape, which results in other errors later on. How can I keep the original shape of images? Before applying the augmentation function my batch of images have shape `(batch_size, None, None, 1)`, but afterwards shape is `<unknown>`.

#### Update #2

I solved the issue with the unknown shape by first finding the dynamic (true) shape of the images and then reshaping the result of applying the augmentation.

```
def augment_fn(self):
    def augment(images, labels):
        img_dtype = images.dtype
        img_shape = tf.shape(images)
        images = tf.numpy_function(self.augmenter.augment_images,
                                   [images],
                                   img_dtype)
        images = tf.reshape(images, shape = img_shape)
        return images, labels
    return augment
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `image.numpy()` instead of `tf.make_array(image)`. However I tried it on a tf.Dataset in TF2.0 and neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this due to non using eager mode? I thought Eager mode was default in TF2.0. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Yes, Dataset pre-processing is not executed in eager mode. This is, I assume, deliberate and certainly makes sense if you consider that Datasets can represent arbitrarily large (even infinite) streams of data.

Assuming that it is not possible/practical for you to translate the augmentation you are doing to tensorflow operations (which would be the first choice!) then you can use `tf.numpy_function` to execute arbitrary python code (this is a replacement for the now deprecated [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#applying_arbitrary_python_logic_with_tfpy_func))

Comment: I took the tensorflow approach (using the tf.image API) in the first place, but considering that I'm using the GPU for training a model deep CNN, it seemed a better idea to rather use the CPU to do the augmentations. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think dataset map operations are done on CPU anyway but I may be out of date or mistaken. I'd need to check. My assertion that it was first choice was based on the docs I linked to.

Comment: It seems you are right, operations in the Dataset API are run in CPU. I got the wrong idea from some blogs explaining how to use the GPU for data augmentation and then using Dataset.map to apply the augmenting operations.

Answer (score 2):

Please go to the [TF Dataset documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#applying_arbitrary_python_logic) to see why you need to return shapes of your images when you are using `tf.py_function` .

```
def tf_random_rotate_image(image, label):
    im_shape = image.shape
    [image,] = tf.py_function(random_rotate_image, [image], [tf.float32])
    image.set_shape(im_shape)
    return image, label
```